# global name browser is not defined error shows in selenium python while using WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from time import sleep
import unittest


class Testawgp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.get("http://www.awgp.org")

   def test_home_screen_components(self):

        self.home_banner = ui.WebDriverWait(browser,15).until(lambda browser: 
        self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('TELL ME MORE'))
        self.homescreen_banner=self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        self.main_window = self.browser.current_window_handle
        self.homescreen_banner.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
        self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.t)
        self.browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
        self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'W')
        self.browser.switch_to_window(main_window)

def tearDown(self):

        self.browser.quit()
```

Error: global name browser is not defined

Can anyone help me solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials for the `unittest` module to overcome the problem you need to change the line:

```
self.home_banner = ui.WebDriverWait(browser,15).until(lambda browser: self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('TELL ME MORE'))
```

To:

```
home_banner = WebDriverWait(self.browser,15).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_link_text('TELL ME MORE'))
```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan. It's works for me by changing self.browser from browser.

Comment: Hi Debanjan, I am able to open the following elemnent in n new tab using this code:  
     
self.home_banner = ui.WebDriverWait(self.browser,15).until(lambda browser: 
     self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('TELL ME MORE'))

self_banner=self.browser.execute_script("window.open('self.home_banner')")

But I am not able to open in new tab using "self.homescreen_banner.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)". 

So can you please let me know why I am not able to open using Keys.CONTROL. ?